# Getting the Star Regex Operator to Fail

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm not sure if my brain is worn out or if I'm just thinking about this too hard. The following code is from the **about_regular_expressions** in the **Ruby Koans**.

```
def test_asterisk_means_zero_or_more
   assert_equal "abb", "abbcccddddeeeee"[/ab*/]  
   assert_equal "a", "abbcccddddeeeee"[/az*/]  
   assert_equal "", "abbcccddddeeeee"[/z*/]  

 # THINK ABOUT IT:
 #
 # When would * fail to match?
end
```

How do you get `*` to fail a match?

When I say fail, I'm assuming they mean they want `assert_equal` to return *nil*. I know one way would be to throw a `\` in front of the `*` to make the regex explicitly look for the `*` character but I'm pretty sure this isn't what they were implying.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Maybe the answer to "when would * fail to match" is "never".

Comment: I actually like this answer a lot better. Its so simple that it has to be what they were thinking.

Comment: `assert_equal nil, "never"[/z*/]` -- Nope doesn't work, still says nil should equal "" :P

Answer (score 31):

Since `*` will always accept the empty string, it will only fail if you have something before or after it that doesn't match.  For example, `ab*c` will fail to match `azc`, since `b*` will not match `z` and `c` will not match `zc`.

Comment: See I thought that too but the way the question appeared immediately after that last assert_equal made me think that they were strictly referring to the `z*` case. Maybe I'm just making things hard on myself.

Comment: @Ryan: If you did `^z*$` (or a matching function that required the whole string to match), that could fail.

Comment: Thanks! I was over thinking it and wanted to be sure I wasn't missing anything. You've confirmed my suspicions.

Answer (score 1):

`assert_equal nil, "abbcccddddeeeee"[/zc*/]`

z doesn't match-- so c* can't match. Tinkered with options until `assert_equal nil` passed.